# printing the data of objects by storing it in variables

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object named data and on console of data, I did :

```js
var data={
     countrycode: "376",
     dob: "2017-05-24",
     email: "bsbsbs@gmail.com",
     firstName: "ggsgsggsg",
     gender: "male",
     phoneNumbers: "88888888888888888",
     surName: "hshshhshs"
    }

let countrycode,iso2,number,firstName,surName,dob,gender,email;
countrycode=data.countrycode;
number=data.phoneNumbers;
firstName=data.firstName;
surName=data.surName;
email:data.email;
gender:data.gender;
dob:data.dob;
console.log('email is',email);
console.log('number is ',number);
console.log('gender is',gender);
console.log('surName is',surName);
console.log('dob is',dob);
console.log('firstName is',firstName);
```

What I see that as i console log the values , i get undefined for email,gender and dob and for rest of the others , i get the correct values .
What can be the reason this and why does this happen ?

Comment: Use ```=``` when setting email, gender and dob.

Answer (score 1):

You have to actually use = as an assignment operator in the example you gave, colons are for object property assignment.

```
email = data.email;
gender = data.gender;
dob = data.dob;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `=` for assignment, not `:` (which is reserved for assigning values to an Object's property).

It would be

```
email=data.email;
```

Not

```
email:data.email;
```

```js
var data={
     countrycode: "376",
     dob: "2017-05-24",
     email: "bsbsbs@gmail.com",
     firstName: "ggsgsggsg",
     gender: "male",
     phoneNumbers: "88888888888888888",
     surName: "hshshhshs"
    }

let countrycode,iso2,number,firstName,surName,dob,gender,email;
countrycode=data.countrycode;
number=data.phoneNumbers;
firstName=data.firstName;
surName=data.surName;
email=data.email;
gender=data.gender;
dob=data.dob;
console.log('email is ',email);
console.log('number is ',number);
console.log('gender is ',gender);
console.log('surName is ',surName);
console.log('dob is ',dob);
console.log('firstName is ',firstName);
```

Comment: I disagree with the suggestion of ```+```. In case of value types it makes no difference (but you need an extra space), and in case of objects it results in ```[object Object]```, which is rarely useful.

Comment: @tevemadar I changed it.